# Proving that half an isometry is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(K,d)$ be a compact metric space and  $f:K\rightarrow K$ such that $$\forall x \in K, \forall y \in K, d(f(x),f(y)) \geq d(x,y)$$

Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

What I managed to prove is that $f$ is bijective (injectivity is trivial, surjectivity I got using contradiction (consider the sequence $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ with $x_0 \not \in K \backslash f(K)$))

All I need to prove further is that $f$ is continuous (automatically since $K$ is compact $f^{-1}$ will be continous)

I don't know how to proceed though... Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is obviously 1-lipschitz, hence continuous. Therefore $f$ is continous. Great !